# RequireJS: returning total function but I need the value, because it is a date module?

Tags: module, requirejs

I am creating a module like this. Because it is a date object, I am writing the code in the `return` block. Otherwise it is giving the same time. So, what I want is if at all, wants to do some functionality with respect to day, date or a property, I have written a function but it is giving total function as an response:

```js
define([], function() {
  var dayarr = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return {
    date: new Date().getDate(),

    day: dayarr[new Date().getDay()],

    year: function() {
      new Date().getFullYear();
    },

    time: new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds()

  }
});
```

Response for property `year`:

```js
function () {
  new Date().getFullYear(); // And some calculation code
}
```

But I want exactly a year.

I followed this link: http://jsperf.com/requirejs-return-object-vs-return-new-instance,
but it is giving total function.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear what you are trying to do.

You defined the `year` property to be a function, so that is what you will get back. You would just need to execute your function.

```
require(["myDateModule"], function (myDateModue) {
    var year = myDateModule.year();
});
```

If you don't want a function, then don't define it to be a function, just like you did for `date`, `day`, and `time`. Those fields all have computed values too.

---

Remember that the function to define a module is called only one time, the first time the module is loaded, then its returned value is cached and used for all other requests for that module. This means that you will get the same date back everywhere that this module is loaded.

If you are trying to get a new Date or run new calculations every tie the module is loaded, then maybe you want to return a function from your module instead?

```
define([], function() {
  var dayarr = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return function() {
    var date = new Date();

    return {
      date: date.getDate(),

      day: dayarr[date.getDay()],

      year: date.getFullYear();

      time: date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
    }
  }
});


require(["myDateModule"], function (myDateModue) {
    var date = myDateModule();
    var year = date.year; 
});
```

Comment: Thank u for your reply. i have require block also. I want to do a functionality in define return property. But if i add a function, it is returning the function itself but not the value. for example i shown in year property. in that i want to check whether it is leap year or not.And need to return that. but total function is returning. @CodingWithSpike